# How can I multithread dasha.ai queue for calling some users simultaneously?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dasha

Is it possible to call some users simultaneously in dasha.ai? Maximum count of simultaneous calls and how can I implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simultaneous calls already implemented via [Conversation Queue](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/sdk/node-js/classes/conversationqueue)

**Simultaneous calls limits**

1. **Instance limit**
   Instance limit is set by you in sdk application.
   It must be initialized through parameter **concurrency** in **application.start** method (default value - 1)

   ```
    await application.start({ concurrency: 10 });
   ```
2. **Group limit**
   All users have a **Default** group which does not have a limit (theoretically infinite)
   However if you are using a custom group - you should set **max-concurrency** to a number of simultaneous calls in it
   You can set and update **max-concurrency** via **dasha cli**
   Example for creating group

   ```
    dasha group create group_name --max-concurrency=50
   ```

   and updating group

   ```
    dasha group update group_name --max-concurrency=50
   ```

   Which group will be used by your application (instance) is defined by deploy method:

   ```
    dasha.deploy("app", { groupName: "Default" });
   ```
3. **Customer limit**
   This limit can be changed only on demand (you can't manually change it, atleast for now)

**Application**

You need to specify how to handle calls via Conversation Queue: for calls that can be started you must specify **ready** event

```
application.queue.on("ready", async (key, conversation) => {
  conversation.input = getInput(key); // getInput must return an object that consist of input variables for a call 
  const result = await conversation.execute();  // start conversation/call
});
```

This event will be started for each call asynchronously

To make simultaneous calls - push as many calls as you need into a queue (example for adding one call into queue, that must be started within one hour or it will be timed out):

```
application.queue.push("some_unique_key", {
    after: new Date(Date.now()),
    before: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000)
});
```

While you have free limits and calls in queue that ready to start - they will be processed as soon as possible